# Udf gives an error (VALUE)

Tags: excel, user-defined-functions, vba

There is a UDF that iterates through the cells of the column and performs primitive actions . It seems that everything is correct , but for some reason gives an error #VALUE!

```
    Function дляппр05(Diapozon As Range) As Long
    'для ситуации
    Application.Volatile
    Dim n As Long
    Dim C As Range

    n = 0
    For Each C In Diapozon.Rows
    If С.Value = 1 And C.Offset(0, 1).Value = 1 Then
    n = n + 1
    End If
    Next C

    дляппр05 = n
    End Function
```

Comment: use `.Cells` instead of `.Rows`

Comment: What range are you passing to the function?

Comment: @ScottCraner , same result

Comment: @TimWilliams , column "R34:R99"

Comment: The `C` in `С.Value` is different then the `C` in `For Each C`

Comment: @ScottCraner ,Now all works !) Thank you !